# Windows 7 for Cloud Databab

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-datalab

I'm interested in trying Cloud Datalab.  The first step seems to be "Run Cloud Datalab locally" which requires Docker ver 1.12.0 or later which requires Windows 10 pro or enterprise.

My system in Win 7 Pro.  Am I correct that I am out of luck here?

Answer (score 1):

**[Run Cloud Datalab locally](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-local)** is one of 3 methods for running Cloud Datalab. You are correct that this specific method on Windows requires **Docker for Windows** (1.12.0 or later), which is only possible with Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise (as indicated on the [Docker for Windows installation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/#/docker-for-windows)).

**[Run Cloud Datalab notebooks on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-gcp-frontend)** is an alternate method which allows you to set up and run Cloud Datalab entirely on Google Cloud Platform, removing the requirement for having Docker on your local machine. As described in the installation steps, use an SSH tunnel to connect to the Cloud Datalab Google Compute Engine virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you cannot do that directly on Windows 7. In my team we decided to [set up Ubuntu on a Virtual Box](http://www.beopensource.com/2016/05/how-to-install-Ubuntu-1604-LTS-in-Virtual-Box-VmWare.html) and work from there, since this was free and easy to set up. That way you can run it locally and you are still inside Windows 7. From there you can follow directly the Docker & Datalab installation guides.